# python bytes to bit string

Tags: python, byte, bitstring

I have value of the type `bytes` that need to be converted to `BIT STRING`

`bytes_val = (b'\x80\x00', 14)`

the bytes in index zero need to be converted to bit string of length as indicated by the second element (14 in this case) and formatted as groups of 8 bits like below.

expected output => `'10000000 000000'B`

**Another example**

```
bytes_val2 = (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 45) #=> '11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000 00000'B
```

Comment: …and the `14`…?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats a simple way to turn bytes into a binary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798952/whats-a-simple-way-to-turn-bytes-into-a-binary-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to binary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python)

Comment: @Błotosmętek - 14 is length of the expected bit string !!

Comment: Should `(b'\x80\x01', 14)` produces also `'1000000 000000'B`?

Comment: What should be the output of `(b'\x08\x00', 14)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about some combination of formatting (below with f-string but can be done otherwise), and slicing:

```
def bytes2binstr(b, n=None):
    s = ' '.join(f'{x:08b}' for x in b)
    return s if n is None else s[:n + n // 8 + (0 if n % 8 else -1)]
```

If I understood correctly (I am not sure what the `B` at the end is supposed to mean), it passes your tests and a couple more:

```
func = bytes2binstr
args = (
    (b'\x80\x00', None),
    (b'\x80\x00', 14),
    (b'\x0f\x00', 14),
    (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 16),
    (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 22),
    (b'\x0f\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 45),
    (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 45),
)
for arg in args:
    print(arg)
    print(repr(func(*arg)))
# (b'\x80\x00', None)
# '10000000 00000000'
# (b'\x80\x00', 14)
# '10000000 000000'
# (b'\x0f\x00', 14)
# '00001111 000000'
# (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 16)
# '11111111 11111111'
# (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 22)
# '11111111 11111111 111111'
# (b'\x0f\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 45)
# '00001111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000 00000'
# (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 45)
# '11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000 00000'
```

---

## Explanation

- we start from a `bytes` object
- iterating through it gives us a single byte as a number
- each byte is 8 bit, so decoding that will already give us the correct separation
- each byte is formatted using the `b` binary specifier, with some additional formatting: `0` zero fill, `8` minimum length
- we join (concatenate) the result of the formatting using `' '` as "separator"
- finally the result is returned as is if a maximum number of bits `n` was not specified (set to `None`), otherwise the result is cropped to `n` + the number of spaces that were added in-between the 8-character groups.

---

In the solution above `8` is somewhat hard-coded.
If you want it to be a parameter, you may want to look into (possibly a variation of) [@kederrac first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61109831/5218354) using `int.from_bytes()`.
This could look something like:

```
def bytes2binstr_frombytes(b, n=None, k=8):
    s = '{x:0{m}b}'.format(m=len(b) * 8, x=int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big'))[:n]
    return ' '.join([s[i:i + k] for i in range(0, len(s), k)])
```

which gives the same output as above.

Speedwise, the `int.from_bytes()`-based solution is also faster:

```
for i in range(2, 7):
    n = 10 ** i
    print(n)
    b = b''.join([random.randint(0, 2 ** 8 - 1).to_bytes(1, 'big') for _ in range(n)])
    for func in funcs:
        print(func.__name__, funcs[0](b, n * 7) == func(b, n * 7))
        %timeit func(b, n * 7)
    print()
# 100
# bytes2binstr True
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 33.9 µs per loop
# bytes2binstr_frombytes True
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 15.1 µs per loop

# 1000
# bytes2binstr True
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 332 µs per loop
# bytes2binstr_frombytes True
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 134 µs per loop

# 10000
# bytes2binstr True
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.29 ms per loop
# bytes2binstr_frombytes True
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop

# 100000
# bytes2binstr True
# 10 loops, best of 3: 37.7 ms per loop
# bytes2binstr_frombytes True
# 100 loops, best of 3: 16.7 ms per loop

# 1000000
# bytes2binstr True
# 1 loop, best of 3: 400 ms per loop
# bytes2binstr_frombytes True
# 10 loops, best of 3: 190 ms per loop
```

Comment: String formatting has a perfectly serviceable binary formatting option for integers, one that doesn’t require slicing of a prefix. Why not use that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was assuming that `>` and `0` specifier would not have worked for `b`, but I was wrong. Thanks for the improvement!

Comment: You don't need `>` at all, it's the default alignment for numbers (each `x` in the `bytes` object `b` is an integer in the interval `[0, 256)`).

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
def bytest_to_bit(by, n):
    bi = "{:0{l}b}".format(int.from_bytes(by, byteorder='big'), l=len(by) * 8)[:n]
    return ' '.join([bi[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(bi), 8)])

bytest_to_bit(b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 45)
```

output:

```
'11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000 00000'
```

steps:

1. transform your bytes to an integer using [int.from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)
2. `str.format` method can take a [binary format spec.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

---

also, you can use a more compact form where each byte is formatted:

```
def bytest_to_bit(by, n):
    bi = ' '.join(map('{:08b}'.format, by))
    return bi[:n + len(by) - 1].rstrip()

bytest_to_bit(b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 45)
```

Comment: Eventually, you may need some extra formatting to handle corner cases for inputs whose binary representation does not start with a `1`. Not specified in the question, though, so not 100% sure, but e.g. `(b'\0f\00', 14)` would not play out well if the required output must have leading `0`s.

Comment: Without a minimum width *leading zeros* will be dropped from your output, so `(b'\x00\x00', 16)` produces `'0'`, not `'0000000000000000'`. You would want to use `"{:0{l}b}".format(int.from_bytes(by, byteorder='big'), l=len(by) * 8)[:n]`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
test_data = [
    (b'\x80\x00', 14),
    (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00', 45),
]


def get_bit_string(bytes_, length) -> str:
    output_chars = []
    for byte in bytes_:
        for _ in range(8):
            if length <= 0:
                return ''.join(output_chars)
            output_chars.append(str(byte >> 7 & 1))
            byte <<= 1
            length -= 1
        output_chars.append(' ')
    return ''.join(output_chars)


for data in test_data:
    print(get_bit_string(*data))
```

output:

```
10000000 000000
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000 00000
```

explanation:

- `length`: Start from target legnth, and decreasing to `0`.
- `if length <= 0: return ...`: If we reached target length, stop and return.
- `''.join(output_chars)`: Make string from list.
- `str(byte >> 7 & 1)`

  - `byte >> 7`: Shift 7 bits to right(only remains MSB since byte has 8 bits.)
  - MSB means Most Significant Bit
  - `(...) & 1`: *Bit-wise and* operation. It extracts LSB.
- `byte <<= 1`: Shift 1 bit to left for `byte`.
- `length -= 1`: Decreasing `length`.

Comment: would you please add some descriptions on what the different lines do? - Thanks !!

Comment: I appended explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

This is lazy version.
It neither loads nor processes the entire bytes.
This one does **halt** regardless of input size.
The other solutions may not!

I use `collections.deque` to build bit string.

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import chain, repeat, starmap
import os  

def bit_lenght_list(n):
    eights, rem = divmod(n, 8)
    return chain(repeat(8, eights), (rem,))


def build_bitstring(byte, bit_length):
    d = deque("0" * 8, 8)
    d.extend(bin(byte)[2:])
    return "".join(d)[:bit_length]


def bytes_to_bits(byte_string, bits):
    return "{!r}B".format(
        " ".join(starmap(build_bitstring, zip(byte_string, bit_lenght_list(bits))))
    )
```

Test;

```
In [1]: bytes_ = os.urandom(int(1e9)) 

In [2]: timeit bytes_to_bits(bytes_, 0)                                                                                                                   
4.21 µs ± 27.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


In [3]: timeit bytes_to_bits(os.urandom(1), int(1e9))                                                                                                 
6.8 µs ± 51 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [4]: bytes_ = os.urandom(6)                                                                                                                        

In [5]: bytes_                                                                                                                                       
Out[5]: b'\xbf\xd5\x08\xbe$\x01'

In [6]: timeit bytes_to_bits(bytes_, 45)  #'10111111 11010101 00001000 10111110 00100100 00000'B                                                                                                        
12.3 µs ± 85 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


In [7]:  bytes_to_bits(bytes_, 14)                                                                                                                   
Out[7]: "'10111111 110101'B"
```

Answer (score -1):

when you say BIT you mean binary?
I would try

```
bytes_val = b'\\x80\\x00'

for byte in bytes_val:
    value_in_binary = bin(byte)
```

Comment: BIT String - string representation of binary.

Answer (score -1):

This gives the answer without python's binary representation pre-fixed `0b`:

```
bit_str = ' '.join(bin(i).replace('0b', '') for i in bytes_val)
```

Comment: getting `TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Is that Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: `>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> bytes_val = (b'\x80\x00', 14)
>>> ' '.join(bin(i).replace('0b', '') for i in bytes_val)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>`

Answer (score -1):

This works in Python 3.x:

```
def to_bin(l):
    val, length = l
    bit_str = ''.join(bin(i).replace('0b', '') for i in val)
    if len(bit_str) < length:
        # pad with zeros
        return '0'*(length-len(bit_str)) + bit_str
    else:
        # cut to size
        return bit_str[:length]

bytes_val = [b'\x80\x00',14]
print(to_bin(bytes_val))
```

and this works in 2.x:

```
def to_bin(l):
    val, length = l
    bit_str = ''.join(bin(ord(i)).replace('0b', '') for i in val)
    if len(bit_str) < length:
        # pad with zeros
        return '0'*(length-len(bit_str)) + bit_str
    else:
        # cut to size
        return bit_str[:length]

bytes_val = [b'\x80\x00',14]
print(to_bin(bytes_val))
```

Both produce result `00000100000000`